# Design alerting service in golang which raises an alert when some conditions are met on DB data

Tags: go, architecture

**My scenario is as follows:**

Dashboard for alerts -

Whenever some conditions are met on existing rows of a table, system has to create some alerts which will be sent to the client.

The client can request for closure of some alerts and, an alert, once closed, should no longer be sent back to client. The service is in golang.

Also, these alerts should have statuses and based on conditions that they meet, the status could change from warning to critical etc.

**Considering the below approach:**

Running a job that queries on DB table against these conditions and whenever some rows meet the condition, add these to a table created for alerts.

One challenge here is to avoid duplicate alerts, older one which would have been a warning vs the same alert being raised as critical now

Please let me know if there are better solutions here - was reading about message queues, but not quite sure if it honors the deletion request from the client.

Using web sockets for the server-client communication. This seems to be working fine.

Looking for suggestions in the service side of things. Also, I'm pretty new to golang. Hence any suggestions with relevant references will be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: "Looking for suggestions" is incredibly broad - what is your question?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask